# Combine gantt, line and bar in apexcharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am trying to plot a chart with a gantt, line and bar series. They work independently, but I can not get them to work together.
It this possible with Apexcharts?

Here is my code so far.

```
var options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Line Chart',
            type: 'line',
            data: [[new Date('2023-04-19').getTime(), 30], [new Date('2023-05-19').getTime(), 40], [new Date('2023-06-19').getTime(), 35],
            [new Date('2023-07-19').getTime(), 50], [new Date('2023-08-19').getTime(), 49], [new Date('2023-09-19').getTime(), 60],
            [new Date('2023-10-19').getTime(), 70], [new Date('2023-11-19').getTime(), 91], [new Date('2023-12-19').getTime(), 125]]
        },
        {
            name: 'Bar Chart',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [[new Date('2023-04-19').getTime(), 30], [new Date('2023-05-19').getTime(), 40], [new Date('2023-06-19').getTime(), 35],
            [new Date('2023-07-19').getTime(), 50], [new Date('2023-08-19').getTime(), 49], [new Date('2023-09-19').getTime(), 60],
            [new Date('2023-10-19').getTime(), 70], [new Date('2023-11-19').getTime(), 91], [new Date('2023-12-19').getTime(), 125]]
        },

        {

            name: 'Gantt Chart',
            data: [{
                x: 'Task 1',
                y: [
                    new Date('2023-04-19').getTime(),
                    new Date('2023-04-22').getTime()
                ],
                fillColor: '#008FFB'
            }, {
                x: 'Task 1',
                y: [
                    new Date('2023-04-23').getTime(),
                    new Date('2023-04-27').getTime()
                ],
                fillColor: '#00E396'
            }, {
                x: 'Task 1',
                y: [
                    new Date('2023-04-28').getTime(),
                    new Date('2023-05-02').getTime()
                ],
                fillColor: '#FEB019'
            }]
        }],

    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'rangeBar',
        stacked: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            horizontal: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },        
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#chart"),
    options
);

chart.render();
```

Stackoverflow wants me to write some more text because I have so much code and not so much text...
One problem I see, is that type: 'rangeBar' and the plotOptions for the gantt chart only work in the global options and I can not specify them at a series.